# Why do I get return false value of key code and not the key code when press second time?

Tags: javascript

Why do I get return false value of key code and not get key code when press second key? With my code

1. when I  press comma (`,`) in text box it's will alert `44` Why not alert `188`?
2. When I press second key why alert `undefined` value ?

```html
<input onkeypress="return test_fn(value)" type="text">

<script>
  function test_fn(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    alert(charCode);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: 44 is comma in ASCII

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when I press comma (,) in text box it's will alert 44 Why not alert 188?

Because `,` is character code 44. If you wanted a *key* code, you'd need to use `keydown` or `keyup`, not `keypress`. But note that some key codes vary from operating system to operating system, or even regional keyboard layout to regional keyboard layout.

> When I press second key why alert undefined value ?

Because you're passing the input's `value` into the function, but then using the argument to the function as though it were an `Event` object. The *first* time, since `value` is blank and therefore falsy, `evt = evt || window.event` grabs the global `event` object (which won't work on Firefox) and so you use the event object. But the *second* time, `","` isn't falsy, so `evt = evt || window.event` keeps using `","` and both `which` and `keyCode` are undefined. Your `onkeypress` should be `onkeypress="test_fn(event)"`.

```html
<input onkeypress="return test_fn(event)" type="text">

<script>
  function test_fn(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    alert(charCode);
  }
</script>
```

...or better yet, don't use `onXYZ`-attribute-style handlers at all, use modern event handling (`addEventListener`, perhaps `attachEvent` if you have to support obsolete browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine.  It returns the value of each character.  Looking on the ASCII table (http://www.asciitable.com/) a comma should return 44.

As for being undefined when you type the second character, it's trying to return the value for the string (both or all characters) not just the newest character typed.  You're grabbing the `value`, not just the most recent character.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that when you call onkeypress, the value of the input has not yet been set, so the value paramater of the test_fn call is null.  So on the first run through fn_call,

```
evt = evt || window.event
```

evaluates to evt = window.event.
Next time you call fn_call, value is set to the value of the input as it was when the key was pressed.  So the evt = ... line above now evaluates to evt = value.  value has no properties named "which" or "keyCode", so alert(charCode) shows undefined.

This code works for me:

```
<input onkeypress="test_fn()" type="text">

<script>
function test_fn() {
  var evt = window.event;
  var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  console.log(charCode);
}
</script>
```